Representing gravity as spherical harmonic expansion causes divergence at poles
I've been looking to how to represent acceleration due to gravity as a spherical harmonic series. One of the terms (roughly equal to the "south" component of gravity) is proportional to $\frac{\partial }{\partial\theta}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))$, where $\theta$ is colatitude. I am calculating:
$\frac{\partial }{\partial\theta}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))=-sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial (cos(\theta))}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))=\frac{m}{tan(\theta)}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))-P_{n,m+1}(cos(\theta))$
This calculation uses this recursion formula from Wikipedia: $(x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}P_n^m(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}P_n^{m+1}(x)+mxP_n^m(x)$
Then I am using $P_{n,m}(x)=(-1)^mP_n^m(x)$.
$\frac{\partial }{\partial\theta}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))$ diverges for $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$, so the acceleration due to gravity is infinite at the poles. Am I calculating this correctly? And if so, does that indicate that this is a limitation of describing gravity as a series of Legendre polynomials?

Well, it certainly doesn’t diverge when $n=m=0$. I tried a few others and none of them diverged. So I think you’ve miscalculated somewhere.

If expansions of fields in spherical harmonics diverged on the $z$-axis, they wouldn’t be very useful.

That makes sense, but what about this equation taken from Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials
$(x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}P_n^m(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}P_n^{m+1}(x)+mxP_n^m(x)$
For x = +-1 and m != 0 this seems to diverge.

Maybe the right side is 0 so you have to take the limit of 0/0.  Try some examples.

For m != 0 and x = 1, the right side becomes m rather than 0. I think it becomes the limit of 0/0 only in cases of m=0.

No, it doesn’t.

If you would just try an explicit example, you would see how wrong you are.

You are correct that the right side is 0 for m!=0. But L'Hopital's rule cannot be used to determine the limit as x->0 because of the recursion. Using L'Hopital's involves taking the derivative of both the numerator and denominator, but the numerator then contains $\frac{d}{dx}P_n^m(x)$, which is the term we are trying to solve.

I tried an explicit example. $\frac{d}{dx}P_1^1(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. This appears to diverge at x=+-1.

Look. I used Mathematica to calculate the limit of $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}P_n^m(\cos\theta)$ as $\theta\to 0$ and $\theta\to\pi$ for $n$ from 0 to 10 and $m$ from 0 to $n-1$. They’re all finite.

The derivatives with $x$ instead of $\theta$ diverge for $m=1$, but that’s not relevant. That’s not the derivative you care about.

You can go worry about L’Hopital. That’s more of a Math SE thing.

@Levi Your most recent example calculates $\frac{d}{dx}P^1_1(x)$ but you need $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}P^1_1(\cos \theta)$, so you're missing a factor of $\frac{dx}{d\theta}=-\sin \theta=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ from the chain rule, which cures the divergence.

Bottom line: You are not calculating correctly. The derivative you care about is finite. It would make no sense for it to diverge since spherical harmonic expansions of fields would then be useless.

@Andrew Wow that is the piece I was missing! My original equation is correct, but your comment makes me realize that any time m != 0 then $P_n^m(cos(\theta))$ will be proportional to $sin(\theta)$ which then removes it from the denominator. Thanks!

There really isn’t any physics here. This is 100% a math question, just in a physics context.

I didn't check your math, but I don't think there is a divergence.
It seems implied in the question that you are talking about the gravity of a spherical planet, maybe rotating--possibly Earth.
This is a solved problem in Geodesy; however, it is usually represented by "The Geoid", which is an imaginary equipotential surface that represents tide-free, bathymetry-free, mean seal level (MSL).
Being a potential, it can be expanded into spherical harmonics ($Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)$). Unclassified results are available at https://cddis.nasa.gov/926/egm96/egm96.html and other US dot gov sites. EGM2008 is even better goes to degree 2190 and order 2159--that's a lot of terms.
If you want to model $\vec g$, then you really need vector spherical harmonics:
$$\vec Y_l^m = Y_l^m \hat r $$
$$\vec \Psi_l^m = r \vec{\nabla}Y_l^m  $$
$$\vec \Phi_l^m = \vec r \times \vec{\nabla}Y_l^m  $$
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics.
But I have not seen this done in practice; rather, ppl use the standard average $\vec g=-g\hat r$ (I think, you need to know which latitude you are using) and then have tables of corrections called "The anomaly ($\Delta g$) and "The deflection" (from vertical).
There is also, now, "The Aeroid", which is the gravity model of Mars. Mars is seriously pear shaped, with the smooth lowlands in the northern hemisphere (which is why we sent all our 1st landers there), and southern hemisphere being high and mountainous--better for scientists, harder for engineers.

Yes, this is the original source of my problem. I wrote a script that implements EGM08. The calculation for the $\hat{\phi}$ component (roughly the "south" component) works out to be proportional to $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))$, but I was under the misconception that that causes divergence at the poles.

try $d/d\cos\theta$, since $d\Omega = d\phi d(\cos\theta)$ may help.

So I understand at this point what is going on. My original equation below is correct:
$\frac{\partial }{\partial\theta}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))=-sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial (cos(\theta))}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))=\frac{m}{tan(\theta)}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))-P_{n,m+1}(cos(\theta))$
However, it doesn't diverge like I thought it did. I believed it diverged because of the $\frac{m}{tan(\theta)}P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))$ term. However, if $m=0$ this term is 0 and if m!=0 then $P_{n,m}(cos(\theta))$ has a $sin(\theta)$ component.
